# Test count is more than data count of data-provider in CodeCeption

Tags: php, phpunit, codeception

I have a `Cest` in CodeCeption which uses a `dataProvider`:

```
<?php


class MyCest
{
    /**
     * @param \Codeception\Example $example
     * @dataProvider MyDataProvider
     */
    public function MyTestCase(Codeception\Example $example)
    {
        echo "Name: ", $example['name'], ", Age: ", $example['age'];
    }

    public function MyDataProvider() {
        $data = [
            ["name" => 'Alice', "age" => 20],
            ["name" => 'Tom', "age" => 35],
            ["name" => 'Bob', "age" => 60],
        ];
        return $data;
    }
}
```

As you see, it returns 3 data items, but when I run the test the log says we have 4 tests:

```
zeinab@zeinab:~/PhpstormProjects/api-testing$ php vendor/bin/codecept run tests/api/MyCest.php 
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.5.1
Powered by PHPUnit 7.1.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
Running with seed: 


Api Tests (4) --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
✔ MyCest: My test case | "Alice",20 (0.00s)ice, Age: 20
✔ MyCest: My test case | "Tom",35 (0.00s)m, Age: 35
✔ MyCest: My test case | "Bob",60 (0.00s)b, Age: 60
✔ MyCest: My data provider (0.00s)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Time: 63 ms, Memory: 10.00MB

OK (4 tests, 0 assertions)
```

I reviewed [PHPUnit DataProvider documentation](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.4/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#data-providers); its example implies that the number of tests are equal to the number of data items returned from `dataProvider` method.

It seems call of the `dataProvider` has been counted as a test case itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All public methods of `Cest` class are executed as tests,
to avoid that make `MyDataProvider` protected or rename it to `_MyDataProvider`
as documented at https://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#DataProvider-Annotations